# Сортировка массива по части строки

Tags: php, строки, сортировка

Здравствуйте. Подскажите такой вопрос

Необходимо отсортировать массив по части строки элемента массива
Исходный

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => 8452-2880FA17-026_2171.jpg
    [1] => 8452-2880FA17-026_21712.jpg
    [2] => 8452-2880FA17-417_2167.jpg
    [3] => 8452-2880FA17-417_2168.jpg
    [4] => 8452-2880FA17-417_2169.jpg
    [5] => 8452-2880FA17-417_2170.jpg
    )
```

отсортированный по части строки

```
Array
    (
    [0] => 2167.jpg
    [1] => 2168.jpg
    [2] => 2169.jpg
    [3] => 2170.jpg
    [4] => 2171.jpg
    [5] => 21712.jpg
    )
```

Как исходный массив отсортировать как по части строки?

Comment: Добрый день. Получается, что Вам надо ещё и значение изменить?

Comment: Нет, это я вырезал по чему должна быть сортировка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно временно модифицировать исходный массив - перезаписать его ключи на значения, по которым надо произвести сортировку. Далее - отсортировать по ключам, и перезаписать исходный массив, отбрасывая временные ключи *(привести структуру массива в исходный вид)*:

```
$array = array(
    '8452-2880FA17-026_2171.jpg',
    '8452-2880FA17-026_21712.jpg',
    '8452-2880FA17-417_2167.jpg',
    '8452-2880FA17-417_2168.jpg',
    '8452-2880FA17-417_2169.jpg',
    '8452-2880FA17-417_2170.jpg'
);

array_map(function($item) use(&$arr){
    $k = preg_replace('~[^_]+_(\d+)\.\w+$~', '$1', $item);
    $arr[$k] = $item;
}, $array);

ksort($arr);
$array = array_values($arr);

var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '8452-2880FA17-417_2167.jpg' (length=26)
  1 => string '8452-2880FA17-417_2168.jpg' (length=26)
  2 => string '8452-2880FA17-417_2169.jpg' (length=26)
  3 => string '8452-2880FA17-417_2170.jpg' (length=26)
  4 => string '8452-2880FA17-026_2171.jpg' (length=26)
  5 => string '8452-2880FA17-026_21712.jpg' (length=27)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно